# Clock function usleep not working right in c program ?

Tags: c, clock

I want to delay my program for 500 msec using clock_t type .For example i have following code  :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t,start_2,end_2,total_2;
   int i;

   start_t = clock();
   printf("start_t = %ld\n", start_t);

   //do a loop
   for(i=0; i< 10000000; i++)
   {
   }

   end_t = clock();


   printf("end_t = %ld \n", end_t);

   total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t)*1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Total1 in msec %ld \n",total_t);



   start_2=clock();
   printf("start_2 %ld\n ", start_2);
   usleep(500000);

   end_2=clock();
   printf("end_2 %ld\n ", end_2);
   total_2=(double)(start_2-end_2)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Total2 in msec %ld\n ", total_2);


   return(0);
}
```

I have found out that usleep takes a value of μsec as an input. So i put 500000.

But i get :

```
start_t = 1041
end_t = 50441 
Total1 in msec 49 

start_2 50446
end_2 50478
Total2 in msec 0
```

What goes wrong ? Why is total2 =0 ? Any help please ?

Comment: *"The clock() function determines the amount of processor time used..."* When you sleep, time passes, but no processor time is used.

Comment: So do i need the delay() function ?

Comment: No, you need to use a different function to measure wall time. On a MAC,  use `mach_absolute_time`. On Windows, it's `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: On linux ?? Just use a different function to delay or to measure time ?

Comment: On linux, I think you're stuck with `gettimeofday`.

Comment: there's also [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution . I wrote a delay function  :

```
void delay (unsigned int msecs) {
clock_t goal = msecs*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000 + clock();  //convert msecs to clock count  
while ( goal > clock() );               // Loop until it arrives.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In fact, clock function records cpu cycle number for this process. When you call the usleep function, the cpu will not provide any time slide for this process.
So the real reason is clock() function. Maybe you can find some functions to get the system time. I think it will work.